# How to transform the coefficients of a summation of cosine functions? (cos(kw)=?)

Tags: calculus, summation

I know the title is confusing. Here is the problem and thanks in advance.

$f(w)= r0 + r1*\cos{w} + r2*\cos(2w) + ... + rn*\cos(nw)$,  $r0,r1,...,rn$ is given.
Since $\cos(nw)$ can be transformed to a function of $\cos(w), \cos(2w) ....$
I want to tranform $f(w)$ to
$f(w)= a0 + a1*\cos{w} + a2*(\cos{w})^2 + ..... + an*(\cos{w})^n$.

My question is: Any relationship between vector r and vector a？ Given r, is there a general formula or algorithm to compute a?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, the [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition) are very useful.  You can relate the 2 sets of coefficients $r_k$ and $a_n$ using the coefficients of the Chebyshevs:

$$T_n(\cos{w}) = \cos{(n w)}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $f(w)=\sum_{0\le t\le n}r_t\cos tw, g(w)=\sum_{0\le t\le n}r_t\sin tw$

So, $f(w)+ig(w)=\sum_{0\le t\le n}r_t(\cos tw+i\sin tw)=\sum_{0\le t\le n}r_t(\cos w+i\sin w)^t$  using [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_Formula).

Now, $$(\cos w+i\sin w)^t=\sum_{0\le u\le t}\binom tu \cos^{t-u}w(i\sin w)^u$$
$$=\cos^tw+\binom t1 \cos^{t-1}w(i\sin w)+\binom t2\cos^{t-2}w(i\sin w)^2+\cdots$$
$$+\binom t{t-2} \cos^2w(i\sin w)^{t-2}+\binom t{t-1} \cos w(i\sin w)^{t-1}+(i\sin w)^t$$

$$=\cos^tw-\binom t2 \cos^{t-2}w(1-\cos^2w)+\binom t4 \cos^{t-4}w(1-\cos^2w)^2+\cdots$$

$$+i\left(\binom t1 \cos^{t-1}w\sin w-\binom t3\cos^{t-3}w\sin^3w+\binom t5\cos^{t-5}w\sin^5w-\cdots\right)$$

Equating the real parts, $$\cos tw=\cos^tw-\binom t2 \cos^{t-2}w(1-\cos^2w)+\binom t4 \cos^{t-4}w(1-\cos^2w)^2+\cdots$$